# Instance of a class influencing all the other instances of that class

Tags: c++

I have to implement a valve class with one variable (boolean true or false representing valve opened/closed). The trick is that only one valve can be open at any given time. Creating a new valve object opened, or opening an existing one should close all the other valves. Valves should be stored in a singly linked list.

It can be probably done the hard way, by implementing a member function open() that goes through the whole list and closes all the valves, then opens the valve which called the function, but theres probably a better way to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since only one valve can be open at any time, it's enough to store a pointer to the valve which is open (e.g.: store it as a static member).

Answer (score 0):

Class design aside, a simple solution would be simply to have a global variable that holds the index of the one valve that is open.

When a valve becomes the one opened, it simply has to set the global variable to its own index.

Thank you for reading.